# TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not list - Its not a list

Tags: python, pygame

I've been following the python flappy bird ai tutorial from techwithtim, and I get this error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\kahra\Desktop\projects\flappy bird ai\flappy_bird_ai.py", line 109, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\kahra\Desktop\projects\flappy bird ai\flappy_bird_ai.py", line 103, in main
    draw_window(win, bird)
  File "c:\Users\kahra\Desktop\projects\flappy bird ai\flappy_bird_ai.py", line 90, in draw_window
    bird.draw(win)
  File "c:\Users\kahra\Desktop\projects\flappy bird ai\flappy_bird_ai.py", line 78, in draw
    rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.img, self.tilt)
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not list
```

My code is like this

```
import pygame
import neat
import time
import os
import random

WIN_WIDTH = 600
WIN_HEIGHT = 800
BIRD_IMGS = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird1.png")))], [pygame.transform.scale2x(
    pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird2.png")))], [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird3.png")))]
PIPE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(
    pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "pipe.png")))
BASE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(
    pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "base.png")))
BG_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(
    pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bg.png")))


class Bird:
    IMGS = BIRD_IMGS
    MAX_ROTATION = 25
    ROT_VEL = 20
    ANIMATION_TIME = 5

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tilt = 0
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.vel = 0
        self.height = self.y
        self.img_count = 0
        self.img = self.IMGS[0]

    def jump(self):
        self.vel = -10.5
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.height = self.y

    def move(self):
        self.tick_count += 1

        d = self.vel*self.tick_count + 1.5*self.tick_count**2
        if d >= 16:
            d = 16

        if d < 0:
            d -= 2

        self.y = self.y + d

        if d < 0 or self.y > self.height + 50:
            if self.tilt < self.MAX_ROTATION:
                self.tilt = self.MAX_ROTATION
        else:
            if self.tilt > -90:
                self.tilt -= self.ROT_VEL

    def draw(self, win):
        self.img_count += 1

        if self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME:
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*2:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*3:
            self.img = self.IMGS[2]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*4:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count == self.ANIMATION_TIME*4+1:
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
            self.img_count = 0

        if self.tilt <= -80:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
            self.img_count = self.ANIMATION_TIME*2

        rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.img, self.tilt)
        new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(
            center=self.img.get_rect(topleft=(self.x, self.y)).center)
        win.blit(rotated_image, new_rect.topleft)

    def get_mask(self):
        return pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)


def draw_window(win, bird):
    win.blit(BG_IMG, (0, 0))
    bird.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()


def main():
    bird = Bird(200, 200)
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))

    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
        draw_window(win, bird)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()


main()
```

I read the other posts with the same problem and I understand it, but `BG_IMG` is not a list like `BIRD_IMGS`. I don't know what to do.

I tried doing `BG_IMGS[0]` to get the first image of the "list" but it says the object is not a list. Why?

Comment: '"Its not a list"* - O course it it a list, because `[i1], [i2], [i3]` is a tuple of lists. A list is `[i1, i2, i3]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[i1], [i2], [i3]` is not the same as `[i1, i2, i3]`

The following is not a list, but a tuple with 3 components, where each component is a list with 1 element:

> ```py
> BIRD_IMGS = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird1.png")))], 
>             [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird2.png")))],
>             [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird3.png")))]
> ```

Change it:

```py
BIRD_IMGS = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird1.png"))), 
             pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird2.png"))),
             pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird3.png")))]
```

Comment: thanks it worked. i thought the problem was on the background not the bird